# How to updateConfiguration in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Try to use `ContextAmbient.current.resources.updateConfiguration` but it doesn't reflect the changes. Also, tried the re-assign context using `createConfigurationContext`.

```
val context = ContextAmbient.current
val config = context.resources.configuration
val locale = Locale("en")
config.setLocale(locale)
context = context.createConfigurationContext(config)
```

Comment: There's already a `ConfigurationAmbient` you can use it directly

Comment: Thanks @MR3YY, Can you explain it further? i m using `ConfigurationAmbient.current.setLocale(Locale.English)` with `context.recreate()` or `context.createConfigurationContext(config)`, but no luck

Comment: Did you solve it? If yes, any explanation how you did it

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger recomposition after updateConfiguration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991087/how-to-trigger-recomposition-after-updateconfiguration)