# How to trigger recomposition after updateConfiguration?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I want to change my app language dynamically, without the need to restart the `Activity` for the results to take effect. What I am doing now is to add a mutable `Boolean` state that is switch and is used by all `Text` elements.

[image]

To change the language I call the following code inside the clickable callback (I use the box as a dummy object, just to test):

```
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
val resources = LocalContext.current.resources
Box( 
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(0.2.dw)
        .background(Color.Red)
        .clickable {
            
            // to change the language
            val locale = Locale("bg")
            configuration.setLocale(locale)
            resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
            viewModel.updateLanguage()
        }
) {
}
```

Then it switches the language value using the `updateLanguage()` method

```
@HiltViewModel
class CityWeatherViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getCityWeather: GetCityWeather
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _languageSwitch = mutableStateOf(true)
    var languageSwitch: State<Boolean> = _languageSwitch

    fun updateLanguage() {
        _languageSwitch.value = !_languageSwitch.value
    }
}
```

The problem is that in order to update each `Text` composable, I need to pass the `viewmodel` to all descendant that use `Text` and then use some bad logic to force update each time, some changes in the view model occur.

```
@Composable
fun SomeChildDeepInTheHierarchy(viewModel: CityWeatherViewModel, @StringRes textResId: Int) {
 
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = if (viewModel.languageSwitch.value) textResId else textResId),
        color = Color.White,
        fontSize = 2.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
        fontFamily = RobotoFont
    )
}
```

It works, but that is some really BAD logic, and the code is very ugly! Is there a standard way of changing the `Locale` using Jetpack Compose dynamically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest solution is to recreate the activity after configuration change:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
Button({
    // ...
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
    context.findActivity()?.recreate()
}) {
    Text(stringResource(R.string.some_string))
}
```

`findActivity`:

```
fun Context.findActivity(): Activity? = when (this) {
    is Activity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
    else -> null
}
```

---

If for some reason you don't wanna do that, you can override `LocalContext` with the new configuration like this:

`MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            CompositionLocalProvider(
                LocalMutableContext provides remember { mutableStateOf(context) },
            ) {
                CompositionLocalProvider(
                    LocalContext provides LocalMutableContext.current.value,
                ) {
                    // your app
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

val LocalMutableContext = staticCompositionLocalOf<MutableState<Context>> {
    error("LocalMutableContext not provided")
}
```

In your view:

```
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
val context = LocalContext.current
val mutableContext = LocalMutableContext.current
Button(onClick = {
    val locale = Locale(if (configuration.locale.toLanguageTag() == "bg") "en_US" else "bg")
    configuration.setLocale(locale)
    mutableContext.value = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
}) {
    Text(stringResource(R.string.some_string))
}
```

Note that `remember` will not live through system configuration change, e.g. screen rotation, you probably need to store the selected locale somewhere, e.g. in `DataStore`, and provide the needed configuration instead of my initial `context` when providing `LocalMutableContext`.

p.s. in both cases you don't need a flag in the view model, if you have resources placed according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization), e.g. in `values-bg/strings.xml`, and so on, `stringResource` is gonna work out of the box.

Comment: Unfortunately for DropdownMenu composable only recreating the activity works!

Comment: @slaviboy `DropdownMenu` content is placed inside the popup, it's kind of a different view, you can provide the context inside the `content` with the updated configuration separately.