# Some of Text Fields do not update when locale change in composable android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
val languages = listOf(
    "en" to "English",
    "vi" to "VietNam",
)


@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    navController: NavController?,
    viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val currentLanguageIndex = viewModel.language.observeAsState().value ?: 0
    SetLanguage(currentLanguageIndex)
    Scaffold() {
        MainUI(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel,index= currentLanguageIndex)
    }
}

@Composable
fun SetLanguage(languageIndex: Int) {
    val locale = Locale(if (languageIndex == 0) "en" else "vi")
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    configuration.setLocale(locale)
    val resources = LocalContext.current.resources
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
//@Preview(device = Devices.AUTOMOTIVE_1024p)
@Composable
fun MainUI(navController: NavController?, viewModel: LoginViewModel,index : Int) {

    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val image = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_login_img)

    var emailValue by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var passwordValue by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    val passwordVisibility = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val focusRequesterEmail = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val focusRequesterPassword = remember { FocusRequester() }

    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    val checkState = remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.White),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
    ) {
//        DropdownDemo(viewModel = viewModel,index = index)
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(index) }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(150.dp)
                .padding(top = 16.dp, end = 8.dp)
                .wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopEnd)
        ) {
            DropDownLabel(languages[selectedIndex].second, onClick = {
                expanded = true
            })
            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
                modifier = Modifier.width(150.dp)
            ) {
                languages.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        onClick = {
                            selectedIndex = index
                            expanded = false
                            scope.launch {
                                viewModel.saveLocale(index)
                            }

                        },
                    ) {
                        DropDownLabel(s.second, onClick = {
                            selectedIndex = index
                            expanded = false
                            scope.launch {
                                viewModel.saveLocale(index)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .scrollable(state = scrollState, orientation = Orientation.Vertical),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(70.dp)
                    .width(140.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
            ) {
                Image(painter = image, contentDescription = null)
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(19.dp))
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.hello),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4,
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.enter_credentials_msg),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                    fontSize = 14.sp
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(0.6f)
                        .padding(
                            start = 16.dp,
                            end = 16.dp
                        ),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = emailValue,
                        onValueChange = { emailValue = it },
                        label = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.email),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2.copy(color = Gray1)) },
                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email,
                            imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                        ),
                        placeholder = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.email),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2.copy(color = Gray1)) },
                        singleLine = true,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .focusRequester(focusRequester = focusRequesterEmail),
                        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                            unfocusedBorderColor = Gray2
                        ),
                        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                            onNext = {
                                CoroutineScope(Default).launch {
                                    keyboardController?.hide()
                                    delay(400)
                                    focusRequesterPassword.requestFocus()
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp))
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = passwordValue,
                        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                            unfocusedBorderColor = Gray2
                        ),
                        onValueChange = { passwordValue = it },
                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
                            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                        ),
                        trailingIcon = {
                            IconButton(onClick = {
                                passwordVisibility.value = !passwordVisibility.value
                            }) {
                                Icon(
                                    painter = painterResource(id = if (passwordVisibility.value) R.drawable.ic_baseline_visibility_24 else R.drawable.ic_baseline_visibility_off_24),
                                    contentDescription = "Visibility button",
                                )
                            }
                        },
                        label = { Text(stringResource(id = R.string.password),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2.copy(color = Gray1)) },
                        placeholder = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.password),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2.copy(color = Gray1)) },
                        singleLine = true,
                        visualTransformation = if (passwordVisibility.value) VisualTransformation.None
                        else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .focusRequester(focusRequester = focusRequesterPassword),
                        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                            onDone = { keyboardController?.hide() }
                        ),
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(25.dp))
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    ) {
                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier.width(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max),
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                        ) {
                            Checkbox(checked = checkState.value, onCheckedChange = {
                                checkState.value = it
                            })
                            Text(
                                stringResource(id = R.string.remember_me),
                                maxLines = 1,
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2.copy(color = Gray1)
                            )
                        }
                        Box(
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd,
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                        ) {
                            OutlinedButton(
                                onClick = {
                                    // TODO
                                },
                                border = BorderStroke(0.5.dp, BlueLight),
                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
                            ) {
                                Text(
                                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.sign_in),
                                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.button.copy(color = BlueLight)
                                )
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(bottom = 8.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.skytech_software_solutions_pvt_ltd),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption.copy(color = Gray1),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun DropdownDemo(viewModel: LoginViewModel,index: Int) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(index) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(150.dp)
            .padding(top = 16.dp, end = 8.dp)
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopEnd)
    ) {
        DropDownLabel(languages[selectedIndex].second, onClick = {
            expanded = true
        })
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier.width(150.dp)
        ) {
            languages.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        selectedIndex = index
                        expanded = false
                        scope.launch {
                            viewModel.saveLocale(index)
                        }

                    },
                ) {
                    DropDownLabel(s.second, onClick = {
                        selectedIndex = index
                        expanded = false
                        scope.launch {
                            viewModel.saveLocale(index)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DropDownLabel(labelName: String, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable(onClick = onClick)
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_language_24),
            contentDescription = "language"
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
        Text(
            labelName, modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )
    }
}
```

when we change the language UI does not update some of text like sign in button and Edit text. but normal text are changing. how do we over come this situation. I have used mutable live data for the viewModel to UI. when we change language and kill the application and restart, then update all the labels.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger recomposition after updateConfiguration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991087/how-to-trigger-recomposition-after-updateconfiguration)

Comment: i cant find the context.findActivity()?.recreate() in my application context. hence your solution is not supported. i just get the string resources to top of the class with var ( variable) and assign that string to the text.

Comment: Why would you use application context? `LocalContext.current` should work fine here, as showed in my answer. `findActivity` function is also attached