# How to change state of the stringResource while changing locale in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, locale, android-jetpack-compose

I am able to change the locale but the stringResource is not changing.

Code for locale changing:

```
private fun setRTL(context: Context) {
    LocaleUtils.setLocale(Locale(ARABIC_LOCALE))
    LocaleUtils.changeToRTLMode(context)
}

fun changeToRTLMode(context: Context) {
    val locale = Locale("ar")
    val applicationRes = context.applicationContext.resources
    val conf = applicationRes.configuration
    val dm: DisplayMetrics = applicationRes.displayMetrics
    conf.setLocale(locale)
    conf.setLayoutDirection(locale)
    applicationRes.updateConfiguration(conf, dm)

    val configuration =
        context.resources.configuration
    configuration.setLocale(locale)
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)
    context.resources
        .updateConfiguration(configuration, context.resources.displayMetrics)
    
}
```

Comment: Have you restarted the Activity after the Locale change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70995273/3585796